# How to normalise values of specific columns

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
  config class       Da1        Da2         Da3        Da4
      f1   sdf 351.54189  6.0096407 1068.465766 1323.02938
      f2   sdf 258.46798 58.7775532  136.351827   43.33182
      f3   sdf  46.18123  0.1496663    2.573316    0.00000
```

I would like to normalise the values of columns `Da1` to `Da4` based on the range of its row. More specfically, the ranges to be normalised are based on each `config`, for example, the values `351.54189  6.0096407 1068.465766 1323.02938` are the range for `f1`. In this case, the maximum value to be considered in the calculation is 1323.02938. To do that, I have written the following script:

```
ttemp <- function(){
  df <- read.csv("/Untitled 3.csv")
  df[,3:6] <- apply(df[,3:6],2,norm)
}

norm <- function(x, maxVal){
  min = 0
  y <- (x-min)/(maxVal-min)
  return(y)
}
```

My question is how can I specify the maximum value in each row? and is the way I applied the correct one to normalise the columns values?

Comment: YOu could just do `scale(df[3:6])`

Comment: Are you doing this by row or column?  If it is by row, then `MARGIN = 2` in `apply `is for column wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function, we can get the `max` value and pass it

```
ttemp <- function(){
  df <- read.csv("/Untitled 3.csv")
  # changed the MARGIN to 1 as it was not clear
  df[,3:6] <- apply(df[, 3:6], 1, function(x) norm(x, max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
  df
  }
```

Or another option is `scale`

```
df[, 3:6] <- scale(df[,3:6])
```

---

In the OP's function, `min` is taken as 0

```
apply(df[, 3:6], 2, function(x) norm(x, max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
#           Da1         Da2         Da3        Da4
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.102243805 1.000000000 1.00000000
#[2,] 0.7352409 1.000000000 0.127614596 0.03275197
#[3,] 0.1313676 0.002546317 0.002408422 0.00000000
```

If this is by row, then change the `MARGIN` to 1

```
t(apply(df[, 3:6], 1, function(x) norm(x, max(x, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this considers the max per column which is not correct. The maximum is per row. In this case, I expect the normalised value of the first config is `0.2657098137 0.0045423336 0.807590356 1`